# Hibernate установка значения для столбца

Tags: hibernate

Есть hibernate, есть обычная таблица энтити. Погуглил не нашел, возможно ли с помощью hibernate на весь столбец поставить значение? Например как set a = 3 в mySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы работаете с Hibernate через JPA API, т.е. через EntityManager, то код должен выглядеть так:

```
EntityManager em = ...;

em.createQuery("UPDATE YourEntity SET a = :newValue")
                .setParameter("newValue", 3)
                .executeUpdate();
```

Если работаете через Hibernate Session API, то всё то же самое, только вместо `javax.persistence.EntityManager` используется `org.hibernate.Session`.

```
Session session = ...;

session.createQuery("UPDATE YourEntity SET a = :newValue")
                .setParameter("newValue", 3)
                .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень помогло и в дальнейшем пригодится. Второй вариант использую я.